# Why are illegally imported vehicles into Mexico with U.S. license plates driven by residents south of the US-Mexico border called chocolate cars?

Tags: terminology

I [read](https://www.nicb.org/news/regional-news/chocolate-car-crackdown-underway-tijuana-starting-border):

> “Chocolate cars” is a term used to describe illegally imported vehicles with U.S. license plates driven by residents south of the border.

Why are they called chocolate cars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Stealing Cars: Technology and Society from the Model T to the Gran Torino*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Stealing_Cars/yK8AAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22chocolate%20cars%22&pg=PA133&printsec=frontcover)
by John A. Heitmann and Rebecca H. Morales (Baltimore, 2014)
presents an alternative view, but as supposition only.  The authors say that the phrase "chocolate cars" is said to be an allusion to the movie *Forrest Gump*; these stolen cars were like that film's box of chocolates in that "you never know what you're gonna get" (p.133)

Answer (score 3):

[Answer](https://redd.it/1bgo0sh) from Reddit user [milesbeatlesfan](https://www.reddit.com/user/milesbeatlesfan):

> It comes from the Spanish word “chueco” which means crooked.

Comment: For an alternative explanation: https://www.google.com/books/edition/Stealing_Cars/yK8AAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22chocolate+cars%22&pg=PA133&printsec=frontcover

Comment: @TimR thanks, great find! Can you please post it as an answer? https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKXbh.png